# Can handler class with activity's context cause memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-handler

I'm wondering if class extends Handler with activity's context in it's constructor may cause
memory leak.

This is my code about that.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    class HandlerWithContext(private val context: Context) : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            super.handleMessage(msg)
            //Do something with context
        }
    }

    private val handlerWithContext = HandlerWithContext(this)

    private fun runMyHandler() {
        handlerWithContext.postDelayed({

        }, 10000)
    }
}
```

I guess it cause memory leak because HandlerWithContext holds activity's context.

But How to deal with activity's context in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 sources of leaks in your code:

- Using context outside the activity lifecycle. You can avoid this by using `applicationContext` instead of `context`
- Additionally, the anonymous class you are using with `handler.postDelayed` holds a reference to the your activity. So you'll need to remove that in onDestroy like this:

```
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handlerWithContext.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
```

Lastly, use leakcanary to detect leaks in your code. Here's the [getting started guide](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Well...  I think I already use static inner class in my code in Kotlin way, different from Java.

Comment: @HyeonSeok Hey sorry, I didn't realise you're using kotlin. I thought the code was in java. You don't need to use inner class in kotlin, that part is good already and shouldn't cause any leak. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll apply that to my code :)